# Что делать если показывает 8 часов при выводе даты

Tags: java

И так, у меня есть клиент, после инициализации я записываю в переменную long `started_time` `Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime()`, потом где-то в коде я получаю эту дату и записываю в новую переменную `timestamp` `Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime()-started_time`, таким образом я получаю сколько времени просто от инициализации клиента.
потом я вывожу это

```java
SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm:ss");
System.out.println(time.format(timestamp));
```

но если прошло времени менее часа, то в `kk` записывается 8, а не 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс Calendar очень плохо подходит для этих целей. Мало того, данный класс по факту является Deprecated  в связи с появлением пакета java.time в java 1.8. Посему я бы поискал другое решение, например, такое:

```
public static String getTime(long startedTime) {
    long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() - startedTime;
    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", 
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(timestamp), 
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timestamp) % 60, 
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timestamp) % 60);
}
```

Comment: спасибо, буду знать